# How to obtain information from facebook graph api then the page is private?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am wondering if there is a way to read (and read only without any changes) an a facebook page (that is not mine) using the facebook graph api.

For example I have this id "90689883513", mostly if I just put it like this https://graph.facebook.com/90689883513?access_token=xxxx I will get all the info I need (I just need the page basic information) but there is pages that if I understand right they are more "private", you can read all the basic info as user but there is no way to grab it from the facebook graph api, am I right ? or there is way to do this and I am missing something ?

I found someone who manged to do the same thing to this pages but I can't understand how he manged to do that.

Comment: Pages can be “restricted”, so that only users satisfying certain criteria can see them. In that case, you need either a user access token for a user that does that, or a page access token (which needs page admin access).

Comment: Thank you for your respond, Does it make sense if I can see the page itself with my normal facebook account but I can't access it with the graph api ?

Comment: As I said, it depends on what kind of access token you are using.

Comment: So far I used my app page access token, following your lead and using the user access token solved the problem, now I am enable to get all the info that I need. Thank you very much ! :)